# The linked framework 'Pods_Runner.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: x86_64. problem

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, apple-m1

I was getting this error when running a simulator. (Using MacBook M1 pro)

[the error message pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV76U.png)

I trying to fix by adding i386 and arm64 to the exclude architect on Xcode but this error message still remain

[the Xcode workspace setting pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td56V.png)

Thanks.

PS. Yesterday it was running properly without any error, but somehow when I save the code then run it again the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

First, flutter clean and delete your podfile.lock and then goto your terminal and run those commands.

```
flutter pub get
```

Then, try this

```
cd ios && arch -x86_64 pod install && cd ../
```